# Expectation of $X_T^4$ when $X_T$ is log-normally distributed

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $X_T$ be a random variable with $$\ln(X_T) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\ln(x)+\frac{T-t}{2},T-t\right).$$
What is $\mathbb{E}\left(X_T^4\right)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

You are given that
$$
\ln(X_T) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\ln(x) + \dfrac{T-t}{2}, T-t \right) \;.
$$

**Simplifications:**

To begin with, let us define
$$
Y := \ln(X_T) \;,
\qquad
\mu := \ln(x) + \dfrac{T-t}{2} \;,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sigma := T - t \;.
$$
Then the given expression is equivalent to the much simpler expression $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$. For this, we already know that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y) = \color{green}{\mu} \;,
\qquad
\mathbb{SD}(Y) = \color{brown}{\sigma} \;,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\mathbb{E}(X_T) = \mathrm{e}^{\color{green}{\mu} + \frac{1}{2}\color{brown}{\sigma}^2} \;.
$$
To get from $\mathbb{E}(X_T)$ to $\mathbb{E}(X_T^4)$, we need an additional step.

**Identities:**

Notice that $\ln(X_T^c) = cY$ for every $c > 0$. Using the identities
$$
\mathbb{E}(cY) = c\mathbb{E}(Y)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\mathbb{SD}(cY) = c\mathbb{SD}(Y) \;,
$$
we obtain $\ln(X_T^c) = cY \sim \mathcal{N}(c\mu, c\sigma)$. From this it follows that
$$
\mathbb{E}(cY) = \color{green}{c\mu} \;,
\qquad
\mathbb{SD}(cY) = \color{brown}{c\sigma} \;,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\mathbb{E}(X_T^c) = \mathrm{e}^{\color{green}{c\mu} + \frac{1}{2}(\color{brown}{c\sigma})^2} \;.
$$

**Final result:**

Now we just need to set $c = 4$, to get the final result

> $$
> \mathbb{E}(X_T^4)
> = \mathrm{e}^{4\mu + \frac{1}{2}(4\sigma)^2}
> = \underline{\underline{x^4 \cdot \mathrm{e}^{2(T-t) + 8(T-t)^2}}} \;.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint

I will let $X_T=X$ and write $\ln X\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ in place of your expressions, for simplicity.

The pdf of the lognormal distribution is $(x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}\exp(\frac{-(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$ for $x>0$. Therefore,
$$
E[X^4]=\int_0^\infty x^4\cdot \frac1{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dx
$$
To compute this, start with the change of variables $z=\ln x$, so that $dz=dx/x$. Then
$$
E[X^4]=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{4z}\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dx=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(4z-\frac{(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,dx
$$
There is a quadratic function of $z$ inside the $\exp()$. The next step is to complete the square so that function becomes $\exp(\frac{-(z-c)}{2\sigma^2})$ for some $c$. Once you have done this, the integrand just becomes a shifted version of the normal cdf, which integrates to one. The result is just the constant you had to multiply by in order to complete the square.